# Ubuntu zsh Prezto themes not show correctly

Tags: shell, ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Now I isntall looks like ugly:

how to must looks like:[image]

How it looks like in my terminal (Ubuntu)

[image]

Maybe is something wrong with my terminal settings or encodding ?

Comment: I suppose your font doesn't support the code points used here.

Comment: the Font problem you need PowerlineSmbols. same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238864/installing-powerline-fonts-for-zsh-prezto-theme/33275188#33275188